# If statement with CGPoint

Tags: objective-c, ios, cgpoint

I need a example of how to use CGPoint with a if statement to check the x and y coordinates

like something like this

```
if(CGPoint == (XCORDINATE, YCORDINATE)){
do stuff
}
```

and then i need a example of how to check the x and y coordinates on a label

```
if(mylabel == (xpoint, ypoint)){
do stuff
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You get various `CGPoint`s position for labels, using their properties. For example if you need to get the `center` point, get `myLabel.center`.

There are functions to create and compare points as described in [CGGeometry Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html).

So for example you can do something like :

```
CGPoint testPoint = CGPointMake(50.0, 50.0);
if(CGPointEqualToPoint(testPoint, myLabel.center)) {
    // the two points equal
}
```

Comment: Ahh i see, hate to burden you, but just a quick question, what if lets say im using a image, and when this label passes over this image it goes to hidden. Instead of making it have to be at exactly these points of mine, can i make it be like a box thats 50-50-50-50? so within this box with all sides that are 50 in lenght?

Comment: so check the link I put. there are other methods to create and compare not just points but rects. your goal seems to be comparing the `frame` properties of two views (`CGRect`s). try one of the methods for checling rects equality, or maybe `CGRectContainsRect()`

Comment: Ahh Thanks Dude! didnt even notice the link. Appreciated

Comment: @Jacob you are welcome, I'll make it a bit more visible for others too

Answer (score 1):

```
if( point.x == XCORDINATE && point.y == YCORNDINATE )
{
   // do stuff
}
```

If you want to check the coördinates of a label you simply do the above,
and you get the location using:

```
CGPoint point = yourLabel.frame.origin;
```